# A clean way to decouple enums from values tied to in JSON payloads so that they are more reusable?

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson, jackson-databind

I've read from other answers to serialise and deserialise an enum of a different underlying value in Jackson, I would have to do something like this in the enum class:

```
public enum LanguageType {
    JSON("json"), 
    HTML("html");

    private String key;

    LanguageType(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static LanguageType fromString(String key) {
        return key == null
                ? null
                : LanguageType.valueOf(key.toUpperCase());
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

With this, Jackson can bind the enum `LanguageType.JSON` to the value `json` and `LanguageType.HTML` to the value `html` during serialising and deserialising.

The problem with this, however, is that it appears to me that I would then be, in a way, coupling the JSON payload's field into the enum.

In the example above, it might work when the JSON payload looks like this:

```
{
   "language": "html"
}
```

However, if there were another payload which also has a `language` field which we can utilise the `LanguageType` enum for the same purpose, but uses a different value in its field, the `LanguageType` cannot be re-used.

For example, if another JSON payload from another service has something like this:

```
{
   "title": "Some Title",
   "language": "lang_html"
}
```

In this other JSON payload, the `LanguageType` enum can't be reused because the key value was meant for the first JSON payload's language field.

Of course, I can recreate another `LanguageType2` enum just for this purpose, like this:

```
public enum LanguageType2 {
    JSON("lang_json"), 
    HTML("lang_html");

    private String key;

    LanguageType2(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static LanguageType2 fromString(String key) {
        return key == null
                ? null
                : LanguageType2.valueOf(key.toUpperCase());
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Now this would work, but it doesn't feel right because I'm repeating 99% of the whole enum simply because it was tied to the first JSON payload. And now, in my application (the non-JSON parts), I just introduced a new confusion of whether to use `LanguageType` or `LanguageType2` in my logic.

How can I make my enum more reusable such that it can still work in Jackson and also in my application without all these additional details that tie to the actual payload fields themselves?

Comment: What about creating `private List<String> key` and provide to enum all kind values which mean given enum: `JSON(Arrays.asList("json", "json_html"))`? You need to use these values in `fromString` method. In `getKey` method you would always return first key on the list.

Comment: @MichałZiober This could work but I'm still somehow mixing information related to the JSON payload in the enum. This would mean whenever I need to handle a new JSON payload which I could potentially reuse the enum, I've to go into the enum file and add that extra information.

Comment: This is a trade off between `enum` and options you need to handle. You can, of course, instead of strict matching (`equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`) can use `contains` or even create a `RegExp` to match as many different options as you can but this is a right way I think. You should definitely have one `enum` to represent different languages. If you do not want to change all the time `enum` and recompile it you can postpone deserialisation to another class where you can load all possible values from properties file.